# VSTO ribbon xml set callback attribute in 'template' for each control type

Tags: .net, xml, vsto, ms-office, ribbonx

I have a C# VSTO Excel add-in that uses XML for the ribbon. In it, there are multiple ToggleButtons that all use the same functions used in their 'getLabel', 'getKeytip', 'getScreentip', 'getSupertip', 'getPressed', & 'onAction' callbacks. Those functions then return the correct value or execute the correct code based on the control's ID.

Is it possible to create a 'template' for these elements that sets these attributes, but allows me to provide the ID?

For example here is what I currently have:

```
          <toggleButton
            id="tb1"
            getLabel="GetLabel"
            getKeytip="GetKeytip"
            getScreentip="GetScreentip"
            getSupertip="GetSupertip"
            getPressed="Togglebutton_GetPressed"
            onAction="Togglebutton_OnAction"/>
          <toggleButton
            id="tb2"
            getLabel="GetLabel"
            getKeytip="GetKeytip"
            getScreentip="GetScreentip"
            getSupertip="GetSupertip"
            getPressed="Togglebutton_GetPressed"
            onAction="Togglebutton_OnAction"/>
          <toggleButton
            id="tb3"
            getLabel="GetLabel"
            getKeytip="GetKeytip"
            getScreentip="GetScreentip"
            getSupertip="GetSupertip"
            getPressed="Togglebutton_GetPressed"
            onAction="Togglebutton_OnAction"/>
          <toggleButton
            id="tb4"
            getLabel="GetLabel"
            getKeytip="GetKeytip"
            getScreentip="GetScreentip"
            getSupertip="GetSupertip"
            getPressed="Togglebutton_GetPressed"
            onAction="Togglebutton_OnAction"/>
          <toggleButton
            id="tb5"
            getLabel="GetLabel"
            getKeytip="GetKeytip"
            getScreentip="GetScreentip"
            getSupertip="GetSupertip"
            getPressed="Togglebutton_GetPressed"
            onAction="Togglebutton_OnAction"/>
```

And I'd like to be able to specify a 'template':

```
          <toggleButtonTemplate
            getLabel="GetLabel"
            getKeytip="GetKeytip"
            getScreentip="GetScreentip"
            getSupertip="GetSupertip"
            getPressed="Togglebutton_GetPressed"
            onAction="Togglebutton_OnAction"/>
```

And then have my ribbon XML be updated to something like:

```
          <toggleButtonTemplate
            id="tb1"/>
          <toggleButtonTemplate
            id="tb2"/>
          <toggleButtonTemplate
            id="tb3"/>
          <toggleButtonTemplate
            id="tb4"/>
          <toggleButtonTemplate
            id="tb5"/>
```

Is something like this possible? If so, how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Use .net BCL for dealing with XML files. You can generate the ribbon XML at runtime and add attributes to the XML files dynamically using the [XmlDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=net-6.0) class from the `System.XML` namespace. See [Adding attributes to an XML node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882143/adding-attributes-to-an-xml-node) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and I think I get what you're saying, but how would I go about making it use the generated ribbon XML?

Comment: @KyleBeckman search along these lines https://stackoverflow.com/a/44264070/495455

Comment: I wanted to report back that I was able to figure it out (took me longer than it should TBH)... I realized that in the Ribbon.cs file that got added alongside the XML, there was the GetCusomUI function that returns the text of the XML. I added some code that "injects" the attributes as needed using the class referenced above. Thanks everybody for the help!